# How to create the permutation and combination of two or more string array list into one combination list

Tags: java, string, combinations, permutation

I want to get the all combinations of  multiple string arraylist

```
String arr1[]={"red","green"}
String arr2[]={"underline"}
ArrayList a=get_Combination(arr1,arr2)
```

input:

```
array 1=["red","green","blue"].
array 2=["bold"].
array 3=["underline"].`
```

output:
combination list should be look like follows

```
[[red],[red,bold],[red,bold,underline],[underline],[underline,bold].......]
```

Comment: Also put what code you have tried to make desirable output ? is it failing or partially working ?

Comment: Should be good see your first approach in order to help you to improve it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Combin {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        final String[][] array = new String[][] {
            new String[] {"red","green","blue"}
            , new String[] {"bold"}
            , new String[] {"underline"}
        };

        final List<String> list = combination(Arrays.asList(array));

        list.stream()
        .forEach(
            System.out::println
        )
        ;
    }

    static List<String> combination(
            final List<String[]> array)
    {
        if(array == null || array.size() < 1) {
            return Collections.<String>emptyList();
        }

        if(array.size() == 1) {
            return Arrays.stream(array.get(0))
                    .collect(Collectors.toList())
                    ;
        }

        if(array.size() == 2) {
            List<String> list1 = Arrays.stream(array.get(0))
                                .collect(Collectors.toList())
                                ;

            List<String> list2 = Arrays.stream(array.get(1))
                                .collect(Collectors.toList())
                                ;

            final List<String> list3 = new ArrayList<>();
            list1.stream()
            .forEach(
                s1 -> {
                    list2.stream()
                    .forEach(
                        s2 -> {
                            list3.add(s1 + ", " + s2);
                        }
                    );
                }
            )
            ;

            final List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
            list.addAll(list1);
            list.addAll(list2);
            list.addAll(list3);

            return list;
        }

        //length > 2
        List<String> list = combination(array.subList(0, 2));

        for(int i=2; i<array.size(); i++) {
            List<String[]> newArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
            newArrayList.add(list.toArray(new String[list.size()]));
            newArrayList.add(array.get(i));

            list = combination(newArrayList);
        }

        return list;

    }
}
```

result:

```
red
green
blue
bold
red, bold
green, bold
blue, bold
underline
red, underline
green, underline
blue, underline
bold, underline
red, bold, underline
green, bold, underline
blue, bold, underline
```

Comment: thank you so much!! but is there any  other way as stream function requires min 24 api level in android studio?.Thank you so much for the help though this is exactly what output i was looking for

Comment: stream forEach change it to for loop, stream array to list, just convert the array to list by yourself, please try it yourself